# Cone metric spaces and fixed point theory

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

These days cone metric spaces, as a generalization of metric spaces, started to be very interesting... 
A special interest for this space is its application to the fixed point theory. On the last papers there is proven that cone metric space is metrazible, and so a lot of theorems in cone metric spaces are merely copies from metric spaces. But still there are theorems which are not a direct consequence form metric spaces.
My question is: How do we know which theorems have to be redundant (direct consequence form metric spaces) and which not?

Comment: What is a cone metric space?

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X05002337

Comment: Interesting. I never heard of them but having a metric with values in a poset like this makes sense. Did you try to google "cone metric"?

Comment: It is a new field of study. Its first paper is in the link and it is published in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=Cone+metric+spaces+and+fixed+point+theorems+of+contractive+mappings&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&channel=fe&client=browser-ubuntu&hl=en ........................................................

Comment: I've read most of the papers, but my question cannot be find there.

Comment: @Emin, in that case I suspect the answer to your question, or part of an answer, is publishable research, and unlikely to get a useful short answer online. You might simply write to some of these authors.

Comment: You are right, but however I wrote here as well, just in case there is someone who may help me with this.